# Usage du terme 'Afro-français'

Tags: usage, société

Peut-on employer en français (il va de soi sans aucune connotation raciste) le terme Afro-Français (ou Noirs français) pour désigner le groupe ethnique formé par les citoyens de la France d'ascendance totale ou partielle d'Afrique noire ?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Afro-Fran%C3%A7ais&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAfro%20-%20Fran%C3%A7ais%3B%2Cc0 … À utiliser avec prudence : consonance avec " Affreux-Français »

Comment: @Personne : Afro, Affreux ne sonnent pas le même, n'est-ce pas ? Peut-on employer aussi Noirs français ?

Comment: On dit plutôt « Français d'origine africaine. »

Comment: @Toto Mais Français d'origine africaine inclut aussi, par exemple, ceux et celles d'origine maghrébine, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Globalement, oui; mais on peut distinguer les deux. D'origine africaine s'appliquant majoritairement aux personnes originaires d'Afrique noire.

Comment: @Toto : Merci. Très bien. Le terme "Noir français" (à la Noir américain) n'est pas d'usage ?

Comment: Je ne l'ai personnellement jamais entendu.

Comment: @Toto : Merci encore.

Comment: @Toto. On peut aussi dire Noirs de France selon wiki au moins : **Les Noirs de France sont, selon le Conseil représentatif des associations noires de France (CRAN), les citoyens ou résidents français d'ascendance subsaharienne, caribéenne ou ultra-marine.**

Comment: @Toto On parlera plutôt de Français d'origine subsaharienne.  Dimitri : les « Noirs » de France se qualifient rarement eux-mêmes de « Noirs », ils se désignent souvent de « [Blacks](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/black) » et on parle de la « communauté black ».

Comment: @None : Merci ! Sans faire l'accord :-)! Personnellement, je crois que vos commentaires (None, Toto, Personne) méritent le statut d'une réponse.

Comment: Pour les anciennes colonies de l'Afrique Occidentale Française, on parle de Sahel https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahel, origine sahélienne ou plus souvent sub-saharienne pour marquer la négritude https://classe-internationale.com/2017/11/27/la-negritude-de-senghor-genese-dun-concept-universaliste/ que l’on ne trouve pas au Maghreb peuplés méditerranéens.

Comment: @Personne : Afro-Français a consonance avec Affro-Français ? Je ne comprends pas.

Comment: @Personne L'article https://classe-internationale.com/2017/11/27/la-negritude-de-senghor-genese-dun-concept-universaliste/ me laisse perplexe. Nègre, négritude...Ces mots ne sont-ils pas considérés racists ?

Comment: Non, ce  n’est pas un concept de Blancs, mais l’affirmation des valeurs de l’Afrique noire par un francophone émérite https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9opold_S%C3%A9dar_Senghor. L’article met bien en opposition les points de vue germanopratins et la réalité africaine exprimée dans l’anti-langage petit-nègre. *La négritude* se vit par elle-même et porte le débat bien plus haut et plus fort que l'intellectualisme politisé. Le regard porté sur l’autre donne le sens au mot, pas le mot lui-même qui reste une projection ambiguë de soi. L'expression/intuition poétique peut ouvrir des portes …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si le terme d'[Afro-Européens](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afro-Europ%C3%A9ens) est relativement commun dans la presse francophone, celui d'Afro-Français l'est beaucoup moins, même si on peut le trouver, bien sûr :

> Etre afro-français ou appartenir à une communauté afro-française ? ([Blog de Mediapart](https://blogs.mediapart.fr/christian-delarue/blog/200718/etre-afro-francais-ou-appartenir-une-communaute-afro-francaise), juillet 2018)

> Élie Nkamgueu, un Afro-Français qui s'assume. ([Le Point](https://www.lepoint.fr/economie/diaspora-elie-nkamgueu-un-afro-francais-qui-s-assume-14-04-2015-1920885_28.php), avril 2015).

On ne parle plus guère d'Afrique Noire de nos jours, mais plutôt d'Afrique [subsaharienne](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afrique_subsaharienne). De même on parle de population d'origine subsaharienne.

> M. Roger Madec attire l'attention de M. le ministre de l'intérieur, de l'outre-mer et des collectivités territoriales sur les contrôles systématiques à l'égard des citoyens français d'origine subsaharienne ou antillaise et originaires du Maghreb ou du Machrek. ([Question écrite au Sénat](https://www.senat.fr/questions/base/2009/qSEQ090709630.html), juillet 2009)

Réponse à la question posée en commentaire : « Peut-on employer aussi Noirs français ? ).

C'est le mot habituel :

> Contrôles au faciès : les jeunes Noirs ou Arabes ont 20 fois plus de chances d'être contrôlés par la police, selon le Défenseur des droits. (Franceinfo, janvier 2017).

Mais pour certains « L'usage du terme « Noir » pour désigner des personnes est régulièrement dénoncé comme porteur de connotations racistes. » ([Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noir_(humain)#D%C3%A9finition,_synonymes_et_usages))

Il est de plus en plus fréquent depuis une trentaine d'années, d'employer le terme de « [black](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/black) » pour désigner les personnes originaires d'Afrique subsharienne ou des Antilles, même si le mot se rencontre encore peu dans la presse.

Pour finir je renvoie à [cet article](http://www.slate.fr/story/52115/noir) de Slate.fr qui, bien qu'assez ancien (2012), fait le tour de la question sur l'emploi du mot « noir » pour désigner ou qualifier des personnes.

Comment: L'utilisation du mot *black* pour désigner un *noir* est controversée et à juste titre combattue car elle tend à considérer *noir* comme insultant et donc à rendre tabou ce mot.

Comment: @jlliagre c'est plus compliqué que ça. Voir l'article de Slate qui me semble, à moi, bien résumer la controverse. Disons que c'est aussi une affaire d'opinion.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue5QOr24TcM&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 0):

Tentative de collation des commentaires.

---

Les termes « Afro-Français » et « Noirs Français » sont très peu usités.

Le terme le plus employé est, à mon avis :

> Français d'origine africaine.

ou

> Français d'origine subsaharienne.

pour différencier d'avec :

> Français d'origine maghrébine.

Par ailleurs, on peut trouver également :

> Noirs de France
>
> Les Noirs de France sont, selon le Conseil représentatif des associations noires de France (CRAN), les citoyens ou résidents français d'ascendance subsaharienne, caribéenne ou ultra-marine.

Cependant, il est à noter :

les « Noirs » de France se qualifient rarement eux-mêmes de « Noirs », ils se désignent souvent de « [Blacks](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/black) » et on parle de la « communauté black ».

Comment: Même commentaire qu'à l'autre réponse: *L'utilisation du mot black pour désigner un noir est controversée et à juste titre combattue car elle tend à considérer noir comme insultant et donc à rendre tabou ce mot.*  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue5QOr24TcM&feature=youtu.be